# Strangely typed Array in Swift

Tags: ios, cocoa, cocoa-touch, swift

I am getting to learn Swift and I encountered strange behavior of the Swift's `Array` class that is not documented, or well, at least I didn't find it anywhere.

When I am creating an `Array` like this:

```
var myRegularArray: Array = [Int]()
```

or like this:

```
var myRegularArray: Array = [1, 2, 3]
```

then everything goes according to the book: the array is being created via regular syntax and is of defined type etc.

**BUT**

When I type something like this:

```
var myStrangeArray = ["Some text", 42]
```

compiler sees this as `NSObject` instance, not an `Array` or even `NSArray`. What is going on if I use this syntax and why is it not `Array` instance?

Comment: It's not `NSObject` but `[NSObject]` that is `Array<NSObject>`.

Comment: agreed with rintaro.

Comment: Ahhh, so Apple's comment about strongly-typed Arrays makes no sense in case I create Array like `Array<NSObject>`?

Comment: @rintaro, could you please write an answer so I would choose it as an answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not `NSObject` but `[NSObject]` that is `Array<NSObject>`.

So why the compiler inferred it as `Array<NSObject>`? Because `NSObject` is the only common type of the elements.

In this case, `"Some text"` is inferred as `NSString`, and `42` is inferred as `NSNumber`. And `NSObject` is the most recent and only common ancestor of them.

Comment: But why can't I access the NSDate element when I put it into array like this:
`let date: NSDate = NSDate()`
`var myRegularArray: [NSObject] = [1, "text", date]`
`println(variable[2])`

Comment: Why `variable[2]`, but not `myRegularArray[2]`? `println(myRegularArray[2])` prints `2014-12-09 10:19:57 +0000` or something.

Comment: You can. But you'd need to cast it to NSDate to work on it as a date.

Comment: The other thing that strikes me... are you sure that an array is the right data structure if you're wanting to put different stuff in it? Maybe a tuple would be more appropriate?

Comment: @rintaro Yeah, my bad, didn't notice. But still, all this means that we actually can have arrays that we got used to from Objective-C, without the restraints the Apple is telling us that all arrays should be explicitly told of which type they use?

Comment: @StephenDarlington yes, that would be the choice, but this specific case is really interesting, as Apple says arrays should be of one type, and here - we create an array that can store, basically, any type we want. Right?

Comment: Yes we can, but we **should not** do like this :) At least, you should explicitly declare the type: `[NSObject]`, `[AnyObject]` or `[Any]`, and state as a comment in the code "Why you need that".

Comment: There are also some weird edge cases with dictionaries. Try `var a = ["b":"c"]` versus `var a = [:]`.

Answer (score 1):

**Whether you use `Any` or `AnyObject` depends on your intended use:**

If your **dictionary** will be used only within Swift code, then you should use `Any` because your types **(Int, Double, Float, String, Array, and Dictionary)** are not objects.

If you will be passing **your dictionary to Objective-C routines** that expect an `NSDictionary`, then you should use `AnyObject`.

When you import Foundation or import UIKit or import Cocoa, it is possible to declare your `array` as `[String: AnyObject]`, but in this case Swift is treating your `Int, Double, Float literals as NSNumber`, your **Strings** as `NSString`, your **Arrays** as `NSArray`, and your **dictionaries** as `NSDictionary`, all of which are objects. A dictionary using `AnyObject` as the value type is convertible to `NSDictionary`, but one using `Any` is not.

We must need to tell compiler, when we supposed to need untyped array at a time of initialization.

Try following that will remove your compile time error

```
 var myStrangeArray :[Any] = ["Some text", 42]
```

Answer (score 0):

In first two examples it tell the compiler that you want an array which contains ints ([Int] or [1,2,3]), however when you create myStrangeArray you pass two different types first is an string and another int so complier is creating array with NSObject: [NSObject].
If you change the declaration to:
`var myStrangeArray = [1, 42]` it will be array with ints: [Int].

Comment: But it doesn't create an array as far as I see, it creates NSbject instance instead of the array, which is weird and that is what makes me curious.

Comment: Are you sure? I tried that and it created [NSObject] type which is array.

Comment: Yeah, you were right, it is an Array that holds NSObject instances, like @rintaro stated